# jQuery event.which returns 13 on Enter key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, line-breaks

Why event.which doesn't return 13 (CR) or 10 (LF) depending on the operating system?

```
$('#something').on('keypress', function (event) {
  switch (event.which) {
  case 13:
    ...
    break;
  }    
});
```

**UPDATE**

I know that Carriage return is equal to 13 in ASCII code. But why Carriage return is common to all operating systems but **produces different outputs** in text (i.e. LF, CR, CR LF)?

Comment: Is there a real problem with this? Consider asking a solution for that problem instead of this... rant?

Comment: +1, it's not a bad question, just had poor first revision.

Comment: I agree with @gdoron. This question is totally valid. I myself have already posted at least one question here in SO that was driven by curiosity and wasn't a problem waiting for a solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because that is the ASCII code for return...

The table:

[image]

Look at number **13**:

> **13**      015       0D       00001101      CR        `&#013;`       **Carriage Return**

Read this:

> The actual codes representing a newline vary across operating systems, which can be a problem when exchanging text files between systems with different newline representations.

Making the value fixed no matter which OS is being used, makes our life a lot easier and letting us focus on the real issues we need to do.

Comment: +1 for your *explicit content* ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan. Thanks, well, pictures are nice... :)

Comment: "The actual codes representing a newline vary across operating systems": so why in this case you always get 13? Is jQuery standardizing the output?

Comment: @collimarco. I believe javascript does it, not jQuery, did you try it in other OS?

Comment: @collimarco. You can test it with [this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zxRQH/).

Comment: Your demo returns 13 on both Mac (Safari) and Windows (Chrome). So it is not jQuery that modify the code.

Comment: @collimarco. So, that's the answer... `:)`